# React - cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to define a function in my component that will redirect the window to a new URL

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

 setWindowLocation = function(e)
 {
    window.location = e;
 }

 handleClick = function(eventKey){
    setWindowLocation("https://google.com") 
 }

 render() {
    ...
 }
}
```

This compiles fine and doesn't throw an error, yet when i click the button that calls 'handleClick' my console window shows:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setWindowLocation' of undefined
> ```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in a React Component in ES6 will be defined like `setWindowLocation()` 
and called like `this.setWindowLocation`

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

 setWindowLocation(location)
 {
    window.location = location;
 }

 handleClick(eventKey){
    this.setWindowLocation("https://google.com") 
 }

 render() {
    ...
 }
}
```

Comment: They *can* be, but if you're using the class property transformation, it'll work fine as written once it's correctly referenced.

Answer (score 3):

You should reference it with `this.setWindowLocation(...)`.

The function is an instance property.